# Hostinger Image Wont' Load

Tags: laravel, hosting, web-hosting, slick.js, laravel-jetstream

I uploaded a website on Hostinger but I have problems with my images. The images isn't being displayed. It is working on my local environment but when I deploy it on hostinger the images won;t display, even the slick.js that i am using for my slider also won't load.I am using Laravel/Jetstream and Livewire for views. Does anyone know how to fix this? Thank you.

This is the Error message that I'm getting
[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dtfU3.png)

This is what I use to get the images

```
<img src="{{ asset('image/svg/imageName.svg') }}">
```

This is what I use to get the js files

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ URL::asset('js/slick.js') }}"></script>
```

Directory for the image

```
root > public > image > svg
```

Directory for the javascripts

```
root > public > js
```

Comment: show the view or code that is trying to reference these files

Comment: Hello, I've added the code, directory, and the image error, i'm not sure if that's where the problem is happening because it's my first time deploying a website.

Comment: what is the `asset(...)` call generating for a URL to the image currently?

Comment: @StephenOstermiller, sorry i didn't noticed when I copy the directory

Comment: @lagbox, sorry but I didn't quite understand the question, if you're referring to the current display of the images, it shows a broken thumbnail